# How do I change background color of Java JComboBox in MacOS when not selected

Tags: java, macos, swing, look-and-feel

How do I change background color of Java **JComboBox** in MacOS when not selected?
I am trying to approximate MacOS Dark appearance introduced in MacOS Mojave with my Java application by setting the colors used by UIManager before I display anything and it mostly works but I have a particular problem with JComboBox, I have added code to set background and foreground

```
    Color whitish       = new Color(250,250, 250);
    Color darkGray      = new Color(30,34,38);
    UIManager.put("ComboBox.background", darkGray);
    UIManager.put("ComboBox.foreground", whitish);
```

But what I find is when the combo is selected (*Rename files based on metadata* screenshot) the background and (text) foreground are adjusted correctly. But when the combo is not selected (*For songs already matched combo* on screenshot) only the foreground has any effect, so the foreground goes from Dark to Light, but the background stays Light so it effectively looks like a an empty whitish block.

[image]

I am using Java 1.8.231 and testing on MacOS Catalina

Comment: @GeorgeZ. no but i dont understand how that fits with problem

Comment: I dont understand why setBackground() has no effect on the combo when not selected, but I think you are onto something because I thought it was a macOS specific issue but actually have same issue with Windows as well.

Comment: Also https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6858351

Comment: @GeorgeZ. Im just using a standard JComboBox, no subclassing or custom renderers at all

Comment: So on Windows the default renderer appears to be com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsComboBoxUI.WindowsComboBoxRenderer - I dont really see how to create a new renderer that can subclass this so behaviour is identical except for the background color, in fact background doesnt seem to be mentioned so Im not clear how it is set.

Comment: I misunderstood the question. Sorry for that ( I deleted my answer and all comments since they were irrelevant). To stay on topic I don't think you can change it with system look and feel. Maybe changing its UI it is possible but one time i tested it and it had a lot of work in order to make ui-friendly.

Comment: @George Z. okay well thanks, but why dont you think its possible to change the background for combo, do seem able to change for other elements (although I also seem to have an issue with JButtons colour as well)

Comment: Because the LAF takes care of painting the component. I know its annoying. But after all it would not be system LAF if random paints would take place...

Comment: You can change the UI by using `combobox.setUI` method.

Comment: I just tested with UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel") and that works, so as you say it is an issue with the system specific L&Feels. The trouble is the Aqua LAF does not really support Dark appearance but that is what Mac users want, I wonder if I can just subclass the Aqua ComboBoxUI class.

Comment: Very tricky so i have decided to use Darcula L&F until Oracle support Dark Mode in standard Java (which looks like it may come with Java 14)

Answer (score 1):

I want to add a answer to this post.

The component selected inside the ComboBox is painted with the following constants

```
UIManager.put("ComboBox.selectionBackground", darkGray);
UIManager.put("ComboBox.selectionForeground", whitish);
```

With this constant you can add this effect

[image]

but you lose the mouse hover effect on the items.

Exist some solution

### With personal ComboBoxUI

You can write the personal ComboBoxUI (how suggest the comment of **George Z**)

This is an example

```
public static class PesonalComboBoxUI extends BasicComboBoxUI {

        protected Color background;

        @Override
        public void installUI(JComponent c) {
            super.installUI(c);

            comboBox.setFont(UIManager.getFont("ComboBox.font"));
            background = UIManager.getColor("ComboBox.background");
            comboBox.setBackground(background);
            comboBox.setForeground(UIManager.getColor("ComboBox.foreground"));
            comboBox.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("ComboBox.border"));
            comboBox.setLightWeightPopupEnabled(true);
            comboBox.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
            comboBox.setFocusable(UIManager.getBoolean("ComboBox.focusable"));
        }

        @Override
        protected ListCellRenderer createRenderer() {
            return new PersonalCellRenderer();
        }

        public class PersonalCellRenderer extends BasicComboBoxRenderer {

            @Override
            public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
                super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
                System.out.println("***");
                setBorder((UIManager.getBorder("ComboBox.borderItems")));
                if (isSelected) {
                    setForeground(UIManager.getColor("ComboBox[item].selectionForeground"));
                } else {
                    setForeground(UIManager.getColor("ComboBox.foreground"));
                }
                setBackground(isSelected || cellHasFocus
                        ? UIManager.getColor("ComboBox.selectedInDropDownBackground")
                        : UIManager.getColor("ComboBox.background"));

                return this;
            }

        }
    }
```

This is the result

[image]

### Use an framework

The configuration of the look&feel with the UIManager is difficult, but exists a look&feel to resolve this problem, this look&feel called [material-ui-swing](https://github.com/vincenzopalazzo/material-ui-swing), this project for the moment is unique to include a theming system, it called MaterialTheming.

With MaterialTheming you can write a personal theme, [this is](https://github.com/TheRolfFR/MaterialDarkTheme) an example. By default, for the moment the look&feel contains 2 themes, the MaterialLiteTheme, and the MaterialOceanic.

This is a screenshot

**MaterialLiteTheme**

[image]

**MaterialOceanicTheme**

[image]

### Solution with the framework

You can develop a personal theme with your needs, not exist some documentation but you can use how example the themes developed, an example [this](https://github.com/vincenzopalazzo/material-ui-swing/blob/masternow/src/main/java/mdlaf/themes/MaterialLiteTheme.java) or [this](https://github.com/vincenzopalazzo/material-ui-swing/blob/masternow/src/main/java/mdlaf/themes/MaterialOceanicTheme.java)

PS: If you will develop the new theme, you can create the PR to add your theme to the repository.

PS: I'm the designator to the MaterialTheming and the contributor of the library material-ui-swing.